# Map dictionary to one of it's values

Tags: python

I've got my variable regions, that is filled with data from database

```
{'region': 'SK', 'hour': 21, 'flag': 1}
```

and I've got this code that I need to change so it fits

```
regions = self.taskreportdao.get_table_data_hours(report_date, 
None if Report03Request.HOUR_CODE_ALL_HOURS == hour else hour) 

data = {}

def process_region(r):
    if not data.has_key(r['hour']):
        data[r['hour']] = []
    data[r['hour']].append(r['region'])    
map(process_region, regions)
return data
```

Right now it returns `{21:['CZ','SK'] }`

but I need it to return `{21: {'flag': 1, 'regions':['CZ','SK'] }}`.

How can I transform the dictionary?

Comment: Is it possible that you confused "creating a map" ("map" meaning a data structure more commonly known as "dictionary" in Python), with "using the `map` function" (creating a new list from a given list where each element is transformed by a function)?

Comment: How do you get from `'flag': 0` to `'emerg_flag': 1,` ??

Comment: one more question, what does your data variable contain? the code is quite confusing, you use the var data but dont show us what it contains. plus didn't you swap last two lines of code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 its very possible, i thought that map function creates map.. sorry for that, i actually intend to create dictionary possibly, the code above i would like to transform, or is it easier now to just replace it altogether?

Comment: @JacobIRR that was my bad copy pasting, sorry

Comment: @Ruli  data variable is blank at the begining, updated the code so you can see mostly everything i use in that part of code.. and no its not swapped

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with your code, I am not sure where the 'CZ' came from in the data but here is my solution:

```
regions = [{'region': 'CZ', 'hour': 21, 'flag': 1} , {'region': 'SK', 'hour': 21, 'flag': 1} ]
data = {}

def removekey(d, key):
    r = dict(d)
    del r[key]
    return r

def process_region(r):
  if r['hour'] not in data:
    new_dict = removekey(r,'hour')
    new_dict['regions'] = [new_dict.pop('region'),'CZ']
    data[r['hour']] = new_dict
  else:
    data[r['hour']]['regions'].append(r['region'])

for d in regions:  
    process_region(d)
    print(data)
    #{21: {'flag': 1, 'regions': ['CZ']}} - 1st iteration
    #{21: {'flag': 1, 'regions': ['CZ', 'SK']}} - 2nd iteration
```

You send dictionary `d` from array or dicts regions to function `process_regions`, where if there is not key `r['hour']` in dict data you create new dictionary without key `hour`, renaming the key region to regions and poping value from dict. Finally you create dictionary data and assign the new dict value to the key `r['hour']`. If the key `r['hour']` is already in data, only regions arrays is extended. You might want to check if the key is not already in the array.

Comment: Hi Ruli I'm sorry for my poorly made questions, to answer (and ask again) the CZ value is there by accident, because i didn't notice i put it in there, the problem is i didnt know what regions looked like until now, the code changed and that means the regions now looks like this `[{'region': 'CZ', 'hour': 21, 'flag': 1} , {'region': 'SK', 'hour': 21, 'flag': 1} ]` that means i'm getting error atm, type error, since i'm accesing list of values.. i just started to work with python, so i'm not sure how to change your code to access it.. sorry if it's still confusing and thanks for your help

Comment: I will look at this later, so please clarify, the output is still a dictionary as in question? What is flag? can that key have different values in each dictionaries? if so what should output look like? How should output look like if hour have different values?

Comment: @Martin I have changed the code according to what you have specified, now it should work just as fine.